# Login Validation - Database populates all data except email and doesn't throw any errors

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I'm so close to completing the login/registration section of my site but I've got some bugs that don't show up in `error_log` or anything.

About an hour ago, the script worked for the most part. It would validate, insert into/check database, and redirect to index.php (located in user directory along with login and register forms).

Contents of index.php:

```
/*
If validation script is successful, continue to $destinationUrl, otherwise, go back to try
again. Ultimately, the TRUE statement's output will be the referring page's URL stored as
$_SESSION['Return_Url'] to send users back to where they were, simply as a convenience.
*/

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['UserData'])) {
    exit(header("location:" . $destinationUrl));
} else {
    exit(header("location:" . $loginUrl));
}
```

That's exactly what I want except one detail: it won't show any user input errors. While trying to fix that, I've managed to screw everything up again and now it still submits data and inserts into the database but doesn't insert  `$email`, and doesn't redirect or anything. On top of that, I don't get any PHP errors so I'm at a loss.

I know the login and registration will work because it did before, but I don't know what I did to cause this issue due to know errors being thrown. I just want the input errors to show up. I'm going to post the original code I copied and edited because what I'm messing with right now is a mess but the validation section is the same.

**I did not write these, they were found online after hours of trying script after script. Only this one worked.** Therefore, I don't understand exactly what's going on with every part of the script, but I do understand the basic mechanics of what happens, or is supposed to happen as far as validation of input data and adding to/checking data against the database when the form is submitted. The only thing that I have absolutely no idea what and how it works is the `output($var)` function

#### Included Scripts

```
$db= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbase); }
function safe_input($db, $data) {
  return htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($data)));
}
/*
Currently, I have no idea about JSON or any other languages. Only a decent
portion of PHP, and HTML, of course. Can I just forget this function and use
{return $var;} instead? Because that would make everything so much easier
and I probably wouldn't even be posting these questions... but it's a new
language to me that I couldn't tell you the first thing about.
*/
function output($Return=array()){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    exit(json_encode($Return));
}
```

#### Validation Scripts

(Both scripts are in one file)

```
<?
require 'config.php';
require 'functions.php';

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action']=='login_form'){
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $email = safe_input($db, $_POST['Email']);
    $password = safe_input($db, $_POST['Password']);

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }elseif($password===''){
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!=''){
        output($Return);
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email='$email' AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $Return['result'] = $_SESSION['UserData'] = array('id'=>$row['id']);
    } else {
        $Return['error'] = 'Invalid Login Credential.';
    }
    output($Return);
}

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action']=='registration_form'){
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $name = safe_input($db, $_POST['Name']);
    $email = safe_input($db, $_POST['Email']);
    $password = safe_input($db, $_POST['Password']);

    if($name===''){
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Full name.";
    }elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter a valid Email address.";
    }elseif($password===''){
        $Return['error'] = "Please enter Password.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!=''){
        output($Return);
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        $Return['error'] = 'The email you entered already belongs to an account, please login.';
    }else{
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tbl (GUID, email, password, entry_date) values(MD5(UUID()), '$email', '".md5($password)."' ,NOW() )");
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db); 
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `tbl' (id,name) VALUES('$id','$name')");
        $Return['result'] = $_SESSION['UserData'] = array('id'=>$id);
    }
    output($Return);        
}
?>
```

I'm not sure how I would echo the `$Return array` values. I tried making a function out of it like so:

```
function inputErr($Return) {
    if($Return['error']!=''){
        output($Return);
    }
}
```

but that didn't work either. Is there a special way to echo an array value? Without the index name attached

Also, if you have any ideas why the email `$var` is not being added to db while everything else is, please, do share! With the script not throwing any PHP errors, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Your `function inputErr($Result)` won't work, as your param is `$Result`, but you are using `$Return`

Comment: MD5 has vulnerabilities. Look at SHA2, and do the encryption client side (as per your second exampl) rather than server side (as per your first)

Comment: Also look at using bound parameters in pdo instead

Comment: Sorry, typo. I just double-checked and in the script I'm trying to run it has `function inputErr($Return)...`. I'll edit the question for future answers. Lately, I've been writing my functions outputs like this: `$result='some result';` and then `return $result;`. Been trying to break that habit because of something I read online about echoing functions written way way returning both options, which is an issue I had. Started using 'return '$string';' for each output and it fixed it right up but this was very recent so the muscle memory is still there to type result instead of return.

Comment: For the email value, you have '$email', either use double quotes or remove the quotes.

Comment: As for the first part of your question, store the $Results to the session, and read/display it in the page you are redirecting to.

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes, I've done some research on `MD`, `SHA`, and the like. I planned on changing it but for testing, it doesn't matter. @Sloan Thrasher - A.) I wasn't sure about that part, whether it needed quotes or to concatenate, just recently started learning SQL. If that's the case then awesome, one problem fixed. I'll give it a try B.) At the end of both scripts, the `$Return['result']=$_SESS...`, do you mean I should do the same for the`$Return['error']=...`?